# ANTLR Parser Null Pointer Exception

Tags: parsing, exception, pointers, null, antlr4

I am trying to put actions into `C` function grammar but getting error.
For example:

```
expressionStatement returns [String value]
    :   expression? ';' {$value = (($expression.value != null)?$expression.value:"") + ";";}
    ;
```

Please review the above rule and let me know if I am doing right to return the expression value. Please note that the rule has condition (`?`).
The grammar is correctly run with `antlr` to generate java files and java files also compiled correctly but when I run it with code to parse then it gives null pointer exception.

Please reply me soon how can I write the actions correctly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If `expression` expression does not match then `$expression == null` so `$expression.value` is a NullPointerExceptions.

Try:

```
expressionStatement returns [String value]
:   expression? ';' {
                     if($expression != null){
                       if($expression.value != null){
                         $value = $expression.value
                       }else{
                         $value = "";
                       }
                       $value  += ";";
                     }
                    }
;
```